# python statsmodels linear regression and multiprocessing pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing, linear-regression, python-multiprocessing, statsmodels

I want to use multiprocessing for linear regression modelling when calculating different confidence intervals for the model.

In this example I'm using the dataset from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linear-regression-in-python-using-statsmodels/.

I've fitted the model. I've viewed the confidence interval `print model.summary()`, and the default confidence interval is 95%. I know that you can set the confidence interval to eg 99% using the `alpha` argument in `model.summary(alpha=0.01)`.

I'd expect the output of my code to be a list of summaries with different confidence intervals. The problem with the code below is that every summary in the list has the same default 95% confidence interval. So clearly passing the different confidence intervals isn't working. But how do I make it work?

Thanks!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
from multiprocessing import Pool

# Data
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\headbrain1.csv')

# Model
df.columns = ['Head_size', 'Brain_weight']
model = smf.ols(formula='Head_size ~ Brain_weight', data=df).fit()

# Summaries 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool()
    summaries_list = pool.map(model.summary, [0.05, 0.04 0.01])   
    print(summaries_list)
```

Comment: You need the `alpha` argument in `summary` method, e.g. use a lambda or partial function instead of plain `model.summary`. (But handling the multiprocessing Pool makes this slower than using a simple loop.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `model.summary()` method in `statsmodels` doesn't directly accept the alpha parameter when used with `Pool.map`. To get around this, you can use a lambda function or Python's `functools.partial` to create a wrapper that accepts the alpha value.

Here's one way to modify your code using a lambda function:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
from multiprocessing import Pool


df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\headbrain1.csv')
df.columns = ['Head_size', 'Brain_weight']
model = smf.ols(formula='Head_size ~ Brain_weight', data=df).fit()

# Function to get summary with different alpha values
def get_summary(alpha):
    return model.summary(alpha=alpha)

# Summaries 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool()
    alphas = [0.05, 0.04, 0.01]
    summaries_list = pool.map(get_summary, alphas)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    for summary in summaries_list:
        print(summary)
```